# magnetostrictive effect due to earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, material-science

is there any magnetic field sensor,which produces stress or strain as output,when that sensor is sensing earth's magnetic field on the surface of earth(0.25 gauss to 0.65 gauss)?or any material/composite which produces magnetostrictive effect (stress or strain) for magnetic field strength of 0.25 gauss to 0.65 gauss?

Comment: It sounds like a very hard proposition to measure magnetostrictive for fields that small. Sensitive magnetometers are usually using other effects to achieve high sensitivity (which extends far below the Gauss range).

Answer (score 2):

A common magnetostrictive composite is the amorphous alloy $Fe_{81}Si_{3.5}B_{13.5}C_{2}$ also known as Metglas . Its saturation-magnetostriction constant, λ, is about 20 microstrains and a magnetic-anisotropy field strength, $H_{A}$, of less than 1 kA/m .

The earth's magnetic field corresponds to about $\frac{1}{2}$ A/m. So this magnetic field will produce very minute(or almost no) strain that will be hard to detect in the first place and not sensitive enough to measure the Earth's magnetic field precisely. As of now magnetostrictive materials are not senstive enough for measuring earth's magnetic field.

Information about Magnetometers that use other effects to measure the field can be seen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer)